# WooCommerce breaking Wordpress Admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've made a clean install of Wordpress on my server and added WooCommerce plugin. Now, some of the pages in the admin panel doesn't display correctly (Dashboard, Media, WooCommerce, etc.).

[image]

This is a clean install, only WooCommerce plugin is active.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Would be useful to include versions of everything: OS, MySQL, webserver, PHP, WordPress, WooCommerce, etc.

Comment: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/known-conflicts/ is provided list of thing that conflict with WooCommerce. I believe this link may fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so there is VERY little information to go on here so here is the general "Wordpress Broke" debugging guide.

1. Disable WooCommerce and see if Wordpress goes back to normal.  If this is the case then you have to Reinstall WooCommerce. This is where http://docs.woothemes.com/document/known-conflicts would come in handy
2. If it is still broken without any plugins then you have to check your directory permissions, file structure, and URL Structure.

99% of the time chrome devtools will be your best friend for debuging these problems. It looks like you are not loading some of the core CSS files so lets look to see if you have a a 404, 403, or 500 error when chrome requests them.

1. Open up chrome and go to the Wordpress admin
2. Right click anywhere on the page and "Inspect Element"
3. Look for the red error icon on the right side (top/bottom) and click it to expend the console.
4. You will probably see the failed requests in there. Make sure the requests are for the correct urls, such as: http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php or http://yourdomain.com/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css
5. If that are valid URLs and you have verified that the files exist on the server then you have to check directory permissions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Best wishes, let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that problem quite a while right now. You can try adding a specialized theme that has WooCommerce support like BootFrame Core theme. Or any other themes supporting WooCommerce -> https://wordpress.org/themes/search/woocommerce/ . Once, I used a WooCommerce, installed the plugin before changing any theme and had to create a new DB because the one I made before got corrupted due to the theme not working with WooCommerce. It's just a rare case but it can happen.